# ffmpeg - Record Audio Volume Equal to the Video Being Played

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to record video on my desktop with the audio on the sound card. But, the volume of the audio recording is much lower than it should be. How can I get the audio to record at the same level that it was playing at when the video and audio were recorded?

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate ntsc -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop  -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast D:\output.mp4
```

I have tried increasing the volume after the video was created using the following command. But, it doesn't sound right, there is a sort of "wah-wah" sound that I can now hear.

```
ffmpeg -i F:\input.mp4 -vcodec copy -af "volume=30dB" F:\output.mp4
```

Comment: 30db sounds too high. Do a recording without the volume filter. After recording, run `ffmpeg -i output -af volumedetect -vn -f null -` to see the mean volume. Then increase it but make sure to not normalize it beyond 0dB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is to record at the same volume. Make sure your output volume from the Windows sound mixer is correct. If your sound card allows it, you could enable a microphone boost, but don't make it clip at 0 dB. (See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/448824/microphone-volume-at-maximum-yet-too-quiet).)

You could also run [`ffmpeg-normalize`](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize/) on the output to normalize to 0 dB peak:

```
ffmpeg-normalize input.mp4 -nt peak -t 0 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -o output.mp4
```

Or even better, use EBU R128 to normalize the loudness (this is the default):

```
ffmpeg-normalize input.mp4 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -o output.mp4
```

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of that tool.)