# Microphone sounds very low - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I have these Marvo HG8944 RED headphones, and the microphone sounds very low when I'm talking to my friends on Discord.
Tried to do some tasks from this thing: [Microphone volume at maximum yet too quiet](https://superuser.com/questions/448824/microphone-volume-at-maximum-yet-too-quiet), but nothing helped.

Maybe I will get a better experience if I put my own question?

Comment: Not sure there's enough here to help solve your problem, some more details might help.

Comment: Ok, then. When I connect these headphones, the microphone sounds very low. Tried the settings from Control Panel and many more, but nothing works. I've been thinking about getting a new microphone, but I don't think that's the best solution, because on my laptop, the headset's mic sounds very good! Probably the PC has something...

Comment: If someone's asking, I don't use Win 10, I use Win 7.

Comment: That's the best I can do...

Comment: Still have this problem... anybody..?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a difference in the jacks on your PC and Laptop.

The mic jack on your laptop is probably an actual mic level input.

The jack on your PC is probably a line in/mic in combo jack, which is a line level input.

There is a big difference in the signal level expected from a mic input vs a line input. Microphone's produce a much lower signal level than line sources, which is why microphone's typically go through a pre-amp before hitting a line level input.

I am going to assume you just have onboard sound on your motherboard, which means you will need to go in to your Realtek (most likely) sound panel and turn on the 'mic boost' for that jack to bring the input up to line-level. Your windows 'recording volume' for the microphone should be 0dB (right click the 'volume' slider and you can change it to decibels). The windows mic boost, if it's there, should be off.

So to summarize:

Set windows recording tab volume for the mic to 'decibels' instead of 'percent'. Set to 0dB. Turn off mic boost in windows recording tab if present.

Go into Realtek Sound Panel. Find and enable mic boost for the line in jack and set the recording 'volume' (it's actually gain, not volume) to max. Test in discord and report back.

Comment: Nope. Still not working. If I set the mic to 0db, I'll sound much lower.

Answer (score 0):

I had EXACTLY this same problem and literally made this account to tell you the fix-
Go to youtube and look up the video "Corsair void RGB Microphone audio boost fix tutorial" by The Beach Badger.

You need to get EqualizerAPO from that video description and follow the instructions he gives you to get into the config files for the microphone (It's really easy, I know hardly anything about computers and I did it perfectly fine without any problems)

Now when you test the microphone in the Windows sound setting file, it will not look like the volume has risen at all. I didn't think it worked until I opened discord and had a friend listen to me in voice chat while I messed with the settings (I had to put mine up to 30 decibels, Beach Badger only puts his up to 10!).

Now if this doesn't work on it's own, I will say I did also previously attempt a couple other fixes, including changing the driver being used to be the default USB driver, so you may have to change that as well as do the fix with Equalizer.
It isn't a big program, it basically just grants you access to edit the files. Even if you don't have a corsair microphone, I think it will work, because you just select which mic you're using from the check list for it to configure itself to!

Hope this works for you too!!