# Microphone issues: Skype, Zoom, Google Meet, Windows Voice Recorder but not MS Teams

Tags: windows-10, skype, microphone, microsoft-teams

I'm doing a lot of onine meetings lately, using multiple platforms. But in general the other party complains that they can't hear me very well. It appears that the sound is being chopped off most of the times. There is eg. 3 seconds nearly nothing recorded, and then for 0.5 seconds it works, and then again not.

These symptoms happen on:

- Skype
- Zoom,
- Google Meet
- Even the Windows voice recorder...

Bizarrely enough, this does not manifest when using:

- Microsoft Teams

### Check microphone volume

I checked the volume of my microphone through Start → Settings → System → Sound → Input → Device Properties

[image: Device properties dialog]

So the volume is set correctly. I tried using multiple values.
I also selected the correct input device, so that's not the problem either.

What can I do/check to get this fixed?

Comment: Are you able to try a substitute microphone?

Comment: First, check what's your "default recording device." Then open the voice configuration on each application to see what device is each of them using as the voice input, whether they use the microphone directly or they use the "default Windows device". Try with each option to confirm that's the problem.

Comment: @John I have a headset lying around but it's one with a split stereo audio + microphone. On my laptop I only have a duo connector. But I doubt that would be a problem since Teams works fine.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the chopping off isn't happening anymore at the moment (but it will probably some time in the future again). But the volume was still way too quit, although in Settings  → System → Sound → Input → Device Properties was already set to **100%**. But now I also did the steps described in [the following answer](https://superuser.com/a/451104/1225721) to set the correction to +20dB and now I'm having a decent sound using the Windows Voice Recorder. I'll see if the problem still surfaces in the future.